# How to check if a string contains a substring from an array and split it

Tags: javascript, split, match

I have an array of string like:

```
var matchCodFisc = ["C.F.", "CF", "Cod.Fisc.", "C.F"]
```

and I want to check if in my string 
(e.g. `var myString= "Cod.Fisc.FGDTFR34L16G643W"`) exists that substring (in this case "Cod.Fisc").
If I found the substring I want to split my string in two parts like `["Cod.Fisc", "FGDTFR34L16G643W"]`. How can I do that using JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could find the string and take the rest. Maybe it is better to sort the pattern array by length descending, because it finds the longest string first.

```js
var matchCodFisc = ["C.F.", "CF", "Cod.Fisc.", "C.F"],
    string = "Cod.Fisc.FGDTFR34L16G643W",
    found = matchCodFisc
        .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
        .find(s => string.startsWith(s)),
    result = [found, string.slice(found.length)];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is cool, +1, i was doing that slice part with regex and filtering this is better

Answer (score 0):

You can use find, includes and split

- First find the matching value from `matchChodFisc` using `find` and `includes`
- Create a regex pattern based on value of `found`
- Split using regex we built and fillter empty values

```js
var matchCodFisc = ["C.F.", "CF", "Cod.Fisc.", "C.F"]
var myString= "Cod.Fisc.FGDTFR34L16G643W"

let found = matchCodFisc.find(val=> myString.includes(val))
let regex = new RegExp(`(${found})`, 'gi')

let splited = myString.split(regex).filter(Boolean)

console.log(splited)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do with [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method using [`Str.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
var matchCodFisc = ["C.F.", "CF", "Cod.Fisc.", "C.F"]
var myString = "Cod.Fisc.FGDTFR34L16G643W";
var resindex = matchCodFisc.findIndex(a => myString.includes(a));

console.log([
  matchCodFisc[resindex],
  myString.split(matchCodFisc[resindex])[1]
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your array into a regular expression:

```js
const matchCodFisc = ["C.F.", "CF", "Cod.Fisc.", "C.F"];
const myString = "Cod.Fisc.FGDTFR34L16G643W";

const splitRegex = new RegExp('('+matchCodFisc.join('|')+')\\w+', 'g');
console.log(splitRegex);
let result = splitRegex.exec(myString)

console.log(result[1])
```